# Show Manipulation Trajectory in Rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I use MoveIt! to control a Kuka Youbot arm in Rviz. Apparently i used the computecartesianpath() to move the arm from point A to B. Afterwards i wanted to display the trajetory from A -> B and tried to use the Trajectory Addon in Rviz but it did not work. Do u have any ideas how i can, at least, prove that the youbot operates in a straight line?
At least i know, that the computed cartesian path has 144 points and my terminal shows any jointangle for each point when i display the trajectory.

---

Edit: Hey!

Thanks for your fast answer Dave, that helped me a lot. Currently i try to implement the rviz plugin in my simulation model.
I tried to use the computecartesianpath()-function in MoveIt! and wanted to use the publishpath-function of rviz_visual_tool afterwards to generate the path:

```
namespace rvt = rviz_visual_tools;
rviz_visual_tools::RvizVisualTools visual_tools("odom_combined");
...
...
double fraction = group.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, 0.01, 0.0, trajectory);
...
visual_tools.deleteAllMarkers();
visual_tools.publishPath(waypoints, rvt::LIME_GREEN, rvt::LARGE);
for (std::size_t i=0; i<waypoints.size(); ++i)
{
     visual_tools.publishAxisLabeled(waypoints[i], "pt" + std::to_string(i), rvt::SMALL);
}
visual_tools.trigger();
visual_tools.prompt("next step");
```

When i try to compile this, i get:
error: no matching function for call to "rviz_visual_tools::RvizVisualTools::publishPath(....)

Can u help me to find a solution, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248299/show-manipulation-trajectory-in-rviz/) by [mutu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28552/mutu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-22**:
@mutu: please don't post answers unless you are actually answering your own question. ROS Answers works a little different from a regular forum: update your question if you have more information, or use comments under answers to interact with other users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You want to see lines traced for the end effector location, like in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FSmZRQh37Q

If so see this tutorial (not merged in yet): https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/pull/45

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2016-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2